# orientdb sql between not working as expected

Tags: sql, orientdb

I have a orientdb database with a document style storage.
I have a class MyDocument with about 300.000 records, stored in a round robin fashion (no custom clustering strategy).

I have a numeric field that tells me the storage day in yyyyMMdd fashion, that gets indexed not uniquely with an SBtree.

Until I do queries such as:

```
select from MyDocument where publishDay=20151101
```

it works nicely: I get about 100 records per day.

if I use a range the pain starts:

```
 select from MyDocument where publishDay between 20151101 and 20151102
```

If I do this query from the console it returns 0 records.

If I do this from the webapp it says

```
"fetched more than 50000 records: to speed up the execution, create an index or change the query to use an existent index"
```

but I already have an index, so it seems I cannot do more that queries on specific dates.
also a trick such as:

```
select * from inputdocument where publishday = 20150102 or publishday = 20150101
```

BTW I use  release 2.0.15

Am I doing something wrong? Have I reached the limit of orientdb with this kind of usage?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your DB in OrientDB 2.0.15 with this small osql script:

```
create class MyDocument extends V;

create property MyDocument.publishDay integer;

create vertex MyDocument set publishDay = 20151101;
create vertex MyDocument set publishDay = 20151101;
create vertex MyDocument set publishDay = 20151101;
create vertex MyDocument set publishDay = 20151101;
create vertex MyDocument set publishDay = 20151101;
create vertex MyDocument set publishDay = 20151101;
create vertex MyDocument set publishDay = 20151102;
create vertex MyDocument set publishDay = 20151102;
create vertex MyDocument set publishDay = 20151102;
create vertex MyDocument set publishDay = 20151102;
create vertex MyDocument set publishDay = 20151102;
create vertex MyDocument set publishDay = 20151102;
create vertex MyDocument set publishDay = 20151103;
create vertex MyDocument set publishDay = 20151103;
create vertex MyDocument set publishDay = 20151103;
create vertex MyDocument set publishDay = 20151103;
create vertex MyDocument set publishDay = 20151103;
create vertex MyDocument set publishDay = 20151103;
create vertex MyDocument set publishDay = 20151104;
create vertex MyDocument set publishDay = 20151104;
create vertex MyDocument set publishDay = 20151104;
create vertex MyDocument set publishDay = 20151104;
create vertex MyDocument set publishDay = 20151104;
create vertex MyDocument set publishDay = 20151104;
create vertex MyDocument set publishDay = 20151105;
create vertex MyDocument set publishDay = 20151105;
create vertex MyDocument set publishDay = 20151105;
create vertex MyDocument set publishDay = 20151105;
create vertex MyDocument set publishDay = 20151105;
create vertex MyDocument set publishDay = 20151105;
create vertex MyDocument set publishDay = 20151106;
create vertex MyDocument set publishDay = 20151106;
create vertex MyDocument set publishDay = 20151106;
create vertex MyDocument set publishDay = 20151106;
create vertex MyDocument set publishDay = 20151106;
create vertex MyDocument set publishDay = 20151106;

create index MyDocument.publishDay NOTUNIQUE;
```

I declared the property "publishDay" as integer and created a NOTUNIQUE index on "publishDay".

and your query works

[image]

also searching by index

[image]

Are there any differences from your schema ?

Comment: apart that I am not extending from a Vertex it is the same thanks

Comment: yes it does. the problems not in the query itself, but in the case sensitivity.
IF you specify "...where publishDay=" or "....where publishday = " it works either way.
Using the between clause "publishDay" is treated as case sensitive, so the query works only if the case is correct.

Comment: Hi, I tried the SELECT with OR operator and BETWEEN but I get some results only if I specify the property name perfectly (case sensitive). Below you can find the queries used:

Comment: select from MyDocument where publishDay = 20151101 or publishDay = 20151104 - works
select from MyDocument where publishday = 20151101 or publishday = 20151104 - 0 results
select from MyDocument where publishDay = 20151101 or publishday = 20151104 - it works only on the first condition
select from MyDocument where publishday = 20151101 or publishDay = 20151104 - it works only on the second condition
select from MyDocument where publishDay between 20151101 and 20151103 - works
select from MyDocument where publishday between 20151101 and 20151103 - 0 results

Comment: I'm using OrientDB 2.1.6, which is your version ?

Comment: I use 2.0.15. tried your queries and It seems I got same result. So the only query that is case insensitive is "select from MyDocument where publishday=20151104", that returns the same values as "select from MyDocument where publishDay=20151104".
BTW thanks for the Help LucaS!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have defined an HASHINDEX, that by definition can't handle ranges. Try using a NOTUNIQUE index (SBTree algorithm)

Comment: well the index was already sbtree, the problem lies elsewhere, the query looks case sensitive when a between is involved.
Is it a bug?

If I write :

select count(*) from InputDocument where publishday = 20151117 
OR
select count(*) from InputDocument where publishDay = 20151117 

the result is the same.

select count(*) from InputDocument where publishDay between 20151117 and 20151118

it works while if I do 

select count(*) from InputDocument where publishday between 20151117 and 20151118

it does not work.
Pretty interesting indeed!!!

Comment: field names are always case sensitive, while classes/clusters aren't. The fact that worked in that case could be misleading, I agree.

Comment: Hi Luca thanks for the answer: actually the orient doc is clear about it it was my fault not to read it properly.
So it is correct that the query with the wrong case ".... where publishday =... " works fine? Shouldn't it return 0 results? what mislead me was that the = operator worked without being case sensitive while the BETWEEN did not.